# unable to get the working of Xero for Oauth2

Tags: java, oauth

I am working on Xero (https://www.xero.com/) Oauth2 integration.
there are two type of application

1) private

2) public

1) In private. we need to upload our public key in xero application and the communication is taken place without tocken.

2) in Public application there are some secret keys and some url for getting tocken.

i am working on public application but getting exception
`$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'urlfetch' or call 'Fetch()'`

I just want to ask. in which case i need temp token. private application or public application.

in my case i din't seen token in private application.
could any any tell, so that i can understand the things

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

As far as I am aware Xero API does not support OAuth2, it uses OAuth1a

Answer (score 0):

For Public Application, you need a valid token to access any secured resources. You need to check the documentation for Oauth to see how Oauth works.

For Xero you will try to get a Request Token first from Xero by presenting certificates and valid Consumer Key and Consumer Secret.

Certificates required are:
1. Xero Entrust Certificate 
2. Signing Certificate

Then after the user authorizes your app, you can get a valid access token to access resources from Xero.
Xero [documentation](http://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/public-applications/)explains it beautifully for public applications.

Please explain your specific problem while connecting. As you have asked a very random high level question, this is high level introduction to xero authentication process.